# enable/install ATI x1250

Tags: 10.10, xorg, graphics, ati, hp

I want to install my ATI x1250 on my ubuntu 10.10, i am running it on a HP 6515b.

But when i run aticonfig it says adapter missing, even when i try to edit 3d settings, it says no mardware detected. So the open source drivers are not working perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Proprietary drivers for ATI x1250 are no longer available (support for this card is not in newest drivers and older drivers (that inlude support for this card) are not available with new Xorg in Ubuntu 10.04 or newer).

There's free (opensource) driver for this card -- radeon -- and it's in default installation of Ubuntu.